# WPF Style Override breaks Validation Error event propagation

Tags: wpf, validation, custom-controls, routed-events

I have a custom control that overrides Window:

```
public class Window : System.Windows.Window
{
    static Window()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Window), new System.Windows.FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Window)));                        
    }
    ...
}
```

It also has a style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Controls:Window}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}">
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle"
            Value="None" />        
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Controls:Window}">
 ...
```

Unfortunately, this breaks the propagation of the Validation.ErrorEvent for my window's contents. That is, my window can receive the event just fine, but I don't know what to do with it to mimic how a standard Window (or whoever) deals with it.

If the validating controls are placed in a standard window, they work. They also work if I just take out the OverrideMetadata call (leaving them inside my custom window). They also work if I leave the OverrideMetadata call, but don't define a custom ControlTemplate. If I leave the template as the default one, the stuff inside properly receive their validation events and use their validation templates.

Why is this happening, and how can I get the stock functionality for handling these validation error events working again, using a custom control template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following ControlTemplate for Window works for me:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Grid Background="White">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}" />
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Validation errors will be invisible if you remove AdornerDecorator